# Why did the Brotherhood Without Banners resurrect, and then serve, Lady Stoneheart?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

When the Brotherhood Without Banners arrives at the Trident, there must have been lots of dead bodies around the place, after the battles that recently happened there and the Red Wedding. I don't see why they took a particular interest in this woman's body — how did they recognize her, and why did Beric decide to resurrect her?

Then she surprinsingly became the leader of the Brotherhood and therefore changes their project, from being neutral and protecting the smallfolk from raiders (of the south and the north), to seeking Lady Stoneheart's personal revenge (against the Lannisters and the Frey).

**In this way the Brotherhood Without Banners became the Brotherhood with a Wolf Banner** (or a Trout), figuratively speaking.

- How did they come by Catelyn and recognize her after being dead for several days in the water?
- Why did they decide to bring her back to life?
- Why is she in charge of the Brotherhood? Does it change the Brotherhood's project?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Harwin](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Harwin), a Winterfell man, was with the Brotherhood when they found the body and recognized her. Here is the quote from [Chapter 42 of AFFC](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/A_Feast_for_Crows-Chapter_42) where Thoros explains what happened:

> The Freys slashed her throat from ear to ear. When we found her by the river she was three days dead. Harwin begged me to give her the kiss of life, but it had been too long. I would not do it, so Lord Beric put his lips to hers instead, and the flame of life passed from him to her. And... she rose. May the Lord of Light protect us. She rose.

This also explains why she is in charge: Lord Beric sacrificed himself to resurrect her.

Comment: I guess the, I guess the orientation change is unexplained.

Comment: Not explicitly. I suppose without a leader they followed someone else with enough authority and the will to lead; which happened to be Stoneheart.

Answer (score 1):

Nymeria found Catelyn in the river and pulled her out onto the shore. When the BWB came upon the scene a member of the BWB named Harwin came upon her body and begged Thoros to raise her up. Harwin had been a loyal and lifelong servant to the Starks, so he would be quite familiar with Catelyn.  He refused and Beric gave her the kiss of life giving his life for hers. There were a good deal of members who left the BWB after that Anguy and Eddric were two, but others stayed. I’m assuming Thoros stayed because he was a believer in the lord of light and felt that his God had a reason to raise her. The others stayed out of loyalty to the Starks or Tullys like Harwin, out of faith like Thoros or simply because they honestly didn’t have anywhere else to go most likely.

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] SE! Please consider [registering](/users/login) your account, which will
[give you access](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account)
to more of the site's features.